# Is there any reason to have a 2 TB HDD divided into two partitions?

Tags: windows-7

I had a HDD replaced and the tech replaced my 1 TB drive with a 2 TB drive and divided it into two partitions.
This is on a Windows 7 PC. This is a secondary drive.

I used to over partition my drives.  Now I try to have as few partitions as possible.

Is there any reason to partition that 2TB drive into 2 partitions?

Comment: **Is there any reason two partitions**" o{{\\\\\\\\]]::;;::;;::;;::;;::> GPT partition table for UEFI is one reason.

Comment: ah yes, GPT and UEFI automatically create 4 partitions.  something like 500mb,32mb,16mb, and the rest for your C drive.  Fortunately, those are all hidden from you.

Comment: They probably used a base image designed that way, so that they can use the same image on 1tb and 2tb disks. They simply restore the base image to the 2tb drive, add a second partition so that "the full capacity is usable" and get on with it.

That said, we're missing an important part of the puzzle - what's on the second partition?

Comment: You probably want to keep the C: logical drive small, certainly less than the full 2TB.  If you ever do a dirty shutdown, then the time to perform the chkdisk is proportional to the size of the system partition.

Answer (score 1):

Today, mainly organizational reasons, and keeping things separate.
My windows is by itself so I can reformat any time with out losing my actual data.  Like pictures,game saves,documents, and etc.  I used junction to point **my documents** and etc to my data partition.

Programs are on another drive/partition to keep them separate.

My documents, are on another partition.

I can delete my programs, or windows without risking my documents.

In the old days, and/or using FAT(2gb hahahaha),FAT32, or some other partition types can't handle over a certain limit so they have to be partitioned.

In those days with clusters size >4k small files wasted tons of storage.  Especially if you were forced to use 32k or 64k clusters because your drive was so big.  However, you could create multiple partition, and keep each one to a size so you can keep 4k cluster sizes.

Those were the days!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of personal preference.

If the second partition is unused, it should be easy to merge it with the first with software such as [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/) or an [alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/minitool-partition-wizard/). Because the native Microsoft Disk Management app does not "understand" many formats, such as ext*n*, used by Linux, for example, I prefer these third-party tools.

There are valid reasons for partitioning, though, e.g. dual-booting (one might be for Linux), or if you wish to encrypt only part of the drive.

My personal preference is, as you state, to have fewer partitions, particularly since Windows has extra partitions for UEFI, boot, restore and other
purposes, and each addition makes life just a bit more complicated.